# Value of Py_None

Tags: python, c, cpython

It is clear to me that `None` is used to signify the lack of a value. But since everything must have an underlying value during implementation, I'm looking to see what value has been used in order to signify the absence of a value, regarding `CPython`.

I understand, based on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/none.html#c.Py_None), that `NoneObject` is a singleton. Since my `c` skills are rusty, my best, amateur guess, would be that the value of `None` would be the pointer to the memory allocated for the `Py_None` object; since it is a singleton this would guarantee uniqueness. Or is it assigned to `c`'s `NULL` which has a value of `0x0000` based on the second answer in [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147713/where-are-null-values-stored-or-are-they-stored-at-all)?

Additionally, the documentation also points out:

> Note that the PyTypeObject for None is not directly exposed in the Python/C API.

Which I'm guessing means you cannot find it searching through source. (Which I did, not knowing where to look, for [`object.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Objects/object.c) naively believing I could understand anything)

But I'm not certain about my opinion on this so I asked.

What is the `c` level value for the `Py_None` object in `CPython`?

Comment: `Py_None` *is* the value.

Comment: `Py_None` is a pointer. You can get the memory address it points to using `id(None)`

Comment: So for `Py_None` it's `value == identity` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Py_None` is a macro definition in `Include/object.h`. It is a an alias for `_Py_NoneStruct` in `object.c` which is a static (as in storage) global variable of `PyObject` type (which is a struct). It is assigned in Python terms to be of `NoneType` (defined right above it in `object.c` and only used once for `_Py_NoneStruct`).

So it's not NULL or any other special value in C, it's a singleton `PyObject` instance of `_PyNone_Type`. As for the `_PyNone_Type` `PyTypeObject` not being exposed, I suppose they refer to the `static` keyword (i.e. internal linkage) which means that the `PyTypeObject` is only accessible within `object.c` and is only used once for the definition of `PyNone`.

Just to add to this a bit, whenever the documentation says that `PyNone` has no type, it should not be taken literally. It has a special kind of type, `NoneType`, which you can still access through the `None` singleton but you can't create new instances or do any other thing you can do with a normal type. There seems to be a hard-coded limitation for not creating new instances, and although I can't find exactly where it's defined in the CPython source you can see its effect when trying to create a new instance:

```
>>> type(None)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> type(None)()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot create 'NoneType' instances
```

EDIT: It seems that the error is thrown from `typeobject.c` when the `tp_new` field is NULL. Surprisingly though `_PyNone_Type` seems to be defined with a non-NULL `tp_new` (points to the static `none_new` in `object.c`). It might be set to NULL afterwards at some point, but it's just an implementation detail and doesn't really make a difference for the scope of your question.

Comment: With regard to your final sentence, I think the reason that no new instances of the `NoneType` type can be created (and the error is raised instead) is because a `tp_new` space in the type struct has been intentionally left out. The error is raised in [this function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0d2e50ea6ac5fa6e7df32dbd4bbbf6da5bcdfdc4/Objects/typeobject.c#l890)

Comment: That's what I figured, @ajcr although it seems to be actually non-NULL ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/HEAD/Objects/object.c#L1466)). It must be set to NULL at some point because there doesn't seem to be another way for this error to be raised.

Answer (score 1):

`Py_None` is `Py_None`, and must be increfed and returned from a function during normal operation if no other value is to be returned. `NULL` is only returned if an exception is to be signaled to the VM, with the actual exception object [created/assigned separately](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/exceptions.html).

Comment: I'm still not getting this.  `Py_None` is `Py_None` is equally as confusing as what I'm trying to ask. From what I understand, `Py_None` must be a `c` level struct, or a similar `c` value. What is the `c` value of `Py_None` would probably be a better question.

Answer (score 1):

`Py_None` is the value of the address of the `_Py_NoneStruct` struct definition.

See [the code](https://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.9/file/753a8f457ddc/Include/object.h#l841):

```
/*
_Py_NoneStruct is an object of undefined type which can be used in contexts
where NULL (nil) is not suitable (since NULL often means 'error').

Don't forget to apply Py_INCREF() when returning this value!!!
*/
PyAPI_DATA(PyObject) _Py_NoneStruct; /* Don't use this directly */
#define Py_None (&_Py_NoneStruct)
```