# NoneType class cannot construct None

Tags: python, python-2.7

For some silly reasons, I recently needed to construct `None`.

My first attempt was to grab `None`'s class and use it.

```
nt = type(None)
```

However, calling `nt` give this error:

```
nt()

TypeError: cannot create 'NoneType' instances
```

This gave me a chuckle and replaced that attempt with:

```
nt = lambda: None
```

This got me to thinking about why this doesn't work. I know that there is exactly one `None` for the interpreter, but this is also true of several other python objects and their constructors do not behave this way.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36415550/2069572) talks about about `None` and it's type heritage but as far as I can tell, this doesn't explain why `type(None)()` results in a `TypeError`.

I'm thinking that it must be related to some error checking that happens for return values of `__new__` in metaclasses, but I'm not sure.

**EDIT**: Not a dup of [Value of Py_None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33121048/value-of-py-none)

That question asks "What is the c level value for the Py_None object in CPython?"

This question is specifically about "why does `type(None)()` produce a runtime error (`TypeError`)". `type(None)` gives us `NoneType` which is an instance of `type`. It is quite odd that calling this results in `TypeError`. As @metatoaster pointed out, this behavior is specific to 2.x. In 3.x `NoneType()` will produce `None`. This is the behavior I expect and apparently the core devs that made the change thought so too.

@metatoaster also provided a source [link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3dd1ccb/Objects/typeobject.c#L742) which look promising. It seems likely that this line is what is producing the runtime error message 'TypeError: cannot create 'NoneType' instances'. I did a regex search of the 2.7.14 tag in the cpython repo for `cannot create .* instances` and this line is the only result.

This is the context for the message:

```
static PyObject *
type_call(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    PyObject *obj;

    if (type->tp_new == NULL) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "cannot create '%.100s' instances",
                     type->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }
...
}
```

There are a few places in the repo that set `tp_new` to `NULL` but none of them have anything to do with `NoneType`

Comment: This works in Python 3, not in Python 2.

Comment: So it does. Interesting. tags updated to reflect

Comment: `type(Ellipsis)` seems to be the same way, in that it won't construct in Python 2 but its constructor just returns the singleton in Python 3.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424516/how-to-inherit-from-python-none

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048643/how-to-create-a-second-none-in-python-making-a-singleton-object-where-the-id-is which any one of these can be duplicate but eh.

Comment: @metatoaster thanks for those links. Both interesting but I don't think that either explain *why* (in python 2.7) `type(None)()` results in `TypeError`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value of Py\_None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33121048/value-of-py-none)

Comment: Specifically: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3dd1ccb/Objects/typeobject.c#L742